# What's the difference between str.fun() / str.fun / fun(str) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, function

I tried googling but couldn't find a precise answer, so allow me to try and ask here. If the question does not seem proper, please let me know and I'll delete it.

In JS you've got three different way of writing certain build in functionalities:

- str.length
- str.toString()
- parseInt(str)

I wonder if there is a reason behind these different ways of writing. As a new user I don't grasp why it couldn't be streamlined as: length(str) / toString(str) / parseInt(str) or with dot formulation.

I however think if I do know the reason behind these differences, it would give me a better understanding of JavaScript.

Comment: these three lines of code do completely different things.

Comment: @DavinTryon I know.. I'm talking purely about the formulation.

Comment: @mesqueeb, Davin is correct. They are no way related.

Comment: in javascript a string object have specific methods as it can be attached.

Comment: If it could be "streamlined", it would be. But then you would have another language and not JavaScript. JavaScript has its own grammar, rules and constructs. The three lines you provided are completely different in their meaning, use and grammar. The key to understanding "why not this" is learning what the first three lines you provided are and why they are like that.

Comment: property, method, function in general

Comment: `.length` is a property (technically a getter method), `.toString` is a method as defined in the String prototype, and `parseInt` is just a normal function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is based around objects. Objects have properties (e.g. a User object may have `name` and `age` properties). These are what define the user and are related to the user. Properties are accessed via dot-notation or brackets notation (to access Eliott’s age, we’ll use either `eliott.age` or `eliott['age']` — these are equivalent).

These properties can be of any type — String, Number, Object, you name it — even functions. Now the proper syntax to call a function in JS is to put round brackets: `eliott.sayHello()`. This snippet actually fetches Eliott’s `sayHello` property, and calls it right away.

You can see Eliott as a box of properties, some of which can be functions. They only exist within the box and have no meaning out of the box: what would `age` be? Whose age? Who’s saying hello?

Now *some* functions are defined at the global level: `parseInt` or `isNaN` for instance. These functions actually belong to the global box, named `window` (because legacy). You can also call them like that: `window.parseInt(a, 10)` or `window.isNaN(a)`. Omitting `window` is allowed for brevity.

```
var eliott = {
  name: 'Eliott',
  age: 32,
  sayHello: function () { console.log('Hello, I’m Eliott'); }
};

eliott.name;       // access the `name` property
eliott.age;        // access the `age` property
eliott.sayHello;   // access the `sayHello` property

eliott.sayHello(); // access the `sayHello` property and calls the function

sayHello(eliott);  // Reference error: `window.sayHello` is undefined!
```

**Note:** Some types (`String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, etc.) are not real objects but do have properties. That’s how you can fetch the length of a string (`"hello".length`) and reword stuff (`"hello, Eliott".replace("Eliott", "Henry")`).

Answer (score 1):

Length is one of the attributes of string in JavaScript. Hence you use string.length to get the length of the string.
toString is a function for string objects, hence we use stringobj.toString(). 
parsInt(str) is a global function which takes string as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is object-oriented, so there are functions or procedures which require first an object to use as `this` in their bodies. `str.length` is a property, both syntactically and semantically. It doesn't require any parameters and represents some quality of the object. `obj.toString()` is a method (a function attached to an object), which doesn't represent any characteristics of the object, but rather operates on its state, computes some new values, or changes the state of the object a lot. `parseInt(str)` is a "global" function, which represents an operation not attached to any type or object.

Under the hood, these three ways may be well implemented with just calling a function, passing `this` as the first parameter (like C# does, for example). The semantic difference is the important one.

So why not use just the third syntax, like for example PHP does? First, it doesn't bloat the global environment with lots of functions which only work for one specific case and type, allowing you to specify any new function you want without breaking the old functionality. Second, it ecourages you to use object-oriented concepts, because you can already see working objects and methods in the language, and can try to make something similar.

And why isn't *parseInt* a method? It can as well be `str.toInt()` without any issues, it's just the way JavaScript designers wanted it to be, although it seems also a bit logical to me to make it a static method `Number.parseInt(str)`, because the behaviour of the function is relevant more to the *Number* type than the *String* type.

Answer (score 0):

Behaviour of these expressions is defined in ECMAScript grammar. You *could* read the specification to understand it thoroughly: [ECMAScript2015 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/). However, as pointed out by Bergi, it's probably not the best resource for beginners because it doesn't explain anything, it just states how things are. Moreover I think it might be too difficult for you to be able to grasp concepts described in this specification because of the very formal language used.

Therefore I recommend to start with something way simpler, such as a very basic introduction to JavaScript: [JavaScript Basics on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics). MDN is a great resource.

But to answer your question just briefly:

- `str.length` is accessing a property of the `str` object.
- `parseInt(str)` is a function call
- `str.toString()` is a call of a function which is a property of the `str` object. Such functions are usually named *methods*.

Functions and methods are in fact very similar but one of the differences (except for the obvious syntax difference) is that methods by default have context (`this`) set to refer to the object which they're part of. In this case inside of `toString` function `this` equals to `str`.

**Note**: Accessing a property (as in `str.length`) could in effect call a getter function but it depends on how the object is defined, and is in fact transparent for the user.

Comment: Straightforward and easy to understand! Thanks!

Comment: "*You should read it to understand it thoroughly: ECMAScript2015 specification.*" - no, I really would not recommend that for a beginner. There are much better ressources to learn JavaScript. The problem with the spec is that it doesn't explain anything, it just states how things are (and requires a broad general understanding).

Comment: Yes, indeed. That's what I said later. But maybe you're right, it wasn't clear enough, I can change that :)